# how can i utilize closure in my code?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a JSON like that :

```
[
   {"data":"a"},
   {"data":"b"},
   {"data":"c"}
]
```

Using JavaScript, I want to add an incremental id field like that:

```
[
   {"data":"a","id":"xx_1"},
   {"data":"b","id":"xx_2"},
   {"data":"c","id":"xx_3"}
]
```

but I want to utilize JavaScript closure for

```
var cnt
```

in my following code how can I do that?

```
var data=[
    {"data":"a"},
    {"data":"b"},
    {"data":"c"}
    ];
    var cnt=0;
    data.map(function(data){
       data.id="xx_"+cnt;
       cnt++;
    })

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

In [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback second argument is `index` so you can use it and don't use unnecessary variable `cnt`, like this

```js
var data = [
  {"data":"a"},
  {"data":"b"},
  {"data":"c"}
];

data = data.map(function (element, index) {
  element.id = 'xx_' + (index + 1);
  return element;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: what if my counter is something else rather based on index?

Comment: @kishan could you clarify what do you mean and give example?

Comment: @kishan in your current question you are trying to implement counter and based on it create id, but it is not necessary because in map there is the same functionality

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `.map` since you only modify the objects in the array. Use `.forEach((value, index) => {})`

```
var data = [
  {"data":"a"},
  {"data":"b"},
  {"data":"c"}
];

data.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    obj.id = 'xx_' + (index + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bcahked/)

```
var data=[
        {"data":"a"},
        {"data":"b"},
        {"data":"c"}
];
var counter = (function () { //this is a closure that will return an incremented count value everytime it is called
  var count = 1; // you can initialize to a different value if you want
  return function () {return count += 1;}
})();
data.map(function(data){
  data.id="xx_"+counter(); //calling the counter method
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: somebody did that I don't know

Comment: please be courteous enough to leave a comment with downvote. thanks

Comment: @gurvinder372 This is an over complicated solution, when you all ready got the `index` argument in the provided handler function.

Comment: @dev-null OP said that his counter may be something else other than index. Also, he mentioned in his question that `I want to utilize JavaScript closure for`. Which is why I posted this solution, otherwise you are right that index would be good enough. However, I don't think I have done enough to warrant so many downvotes.